# Pass instantiated class variable as argument

Tags: c#

Say, in C++, the following code is legal and widely used:

```
ObjectType myObject = ObjectType(vector3(10, 9, 3), vector3(40, 0, 0), vector3());
```

I use constructors passed as arguments to a constructor to avoid having to create a bunch of temporary variables I'll throw away later.

If I try this in C#, like thus:

```
ObjectType myObject = new ObjectType(vector3(10, 9, 3), vector3(40, 0, 0), vector3());
```

I get the compiler error

`error CS0118: 'myObject' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'`

Am I making a fundamental error in how I use C#, or is there some workaround I can do?

(Assume that the vector3 class has a default constructor that accepts no arguments, and a constructor that accepts three integers)

Comment: sounds like you have a class that is named `myObject`

Comment: C++ classes behave like value types in C#.  You'd typically declare vector3 as a value type in C# as well, using the *struct* keyword.  The C# language attempts to hide the difference, you still have to use the *new* keyword.

Comment: The `ObjectType` accepts three `int`s? vector3 isn't an `int`, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I use constructors passed as arguments to a constructor to avoid
>   having to create a bunch of temporary variables I'll throw away later.

You are not creating and passing temporary objects,

Use `new` keyword while creating objects like:

```
ObjectType myObject = new ObjectType(new vector3(10, 9, 3), new vector3(40, 0, 0), new vector3());
                                   //^^^^
```

Comment: and if `vector(int, int, int)` returned what was expected as a paramter in the constructor of `ObjectType`?